# LibGdx: How do I use Table Add Actor At (int index, Actor actor)?

Tags: libgdx

Is there any examples of this method being used? I'm not sure what index represents. Is it a row or column number ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table extends WidgetGroup extends Group`. So Table is ultimately also a `Group` and actually Group is the one defining the `addActorAt(int, Actor)` method.

That being said, Table does not override this method, which is why it should not be used. Using it will not work. Instead use only the `Table.add(...)` methods and ignore the `addActor...` ones.

If you want to insert a cell somewhere at the "beginning" of the Table, you will usually have to do a `Table.clear()` and set up all rows and columns from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. Damn, I was hoping this method would allow me to insert an Actor at row 0 etc.